# Which is better for multiple actions in a class? Anonymous inner classes or if statements in actionPerformed()?

Tags: java, swing, events, awt

I am working on making menus in a java JFrame. I've seen two ways of having different responses to different events in the same class. One is to use anonymous inner classes as described in this answer from a few years ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10472395/5960074

```
public static void createMenuBar()
{
    //Main Menu Items

    menubar.add(fileMenu);
    MainWindow.window.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    //Sub menu items
    saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
    loadItem = new JMenuItem("Load");

    //Add to the "File" menu item
    fileMenu.add(saveItem);
    fileMenu.add(loadItem);

    //Anonymous Inner classes for actionListeners


    //Action event for saving
    saveItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ //adding the listener
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ //creating the specific action for save
            System.out.println("You tried to save.");
        }
    });

}
```

In my code it looks like this and it works (as in at this point it prints "You tried to save." to the console).

I've seen other people implement ActionListener in the class and then in the method actionPerformed() they use if statements that track the source of the event. So there is one event but the code changes on what triggers it.

The first method seems messy and the second easier to read. Is there a reason to do the first method over the second?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is, neither and both. It will come down to needs. The `Action` API is another approach which allows for generating reusable code blocks

Comment: Can you think of reasons why one or the other would work better? I'm trying to set up a menubar with this class that allows the user to save and load data.

Comment: What is "better" is asking for opinions. Apply the different styles, and experience how they influence readability and when to switch from one to another.

Comment: It’s all about context - personally I prefer either the Action or anonymous class, they both provide a focused controller which doesn’t rely on assumptions or extra configuration which can change and can be difficult to maintain or understand. Action provides a self contained/configurable unit of work, which, if your clever, can be used to generate layers of abstraction. Think about save and open - the only real difference is one writes and one reads, but otherwise they want to perform the same basic operations, prompt the user for a file

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Action](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) class with non-anonymous classes (they can be static inner classes though). It gives you nice encapsulation, makes the code readable and is in many ways better than using `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 1):

First, avoid using `static`, you really (really) don't need it, it promotes bad code design.

Assuming you use Java 8, and thus can use lambda's:

```
public void createMenuBar() {
   ...
   saveItem.addActionListener(this::save);
   loadItem.addActionListener(this::load);
} 

private save(ActionEvent e) { 
    .... 
}

private load(ActionEvent e) { 
   .... 
}
```

If you cannot use lambdas using inner classes is better than implementing the interface and using `if` statements.

```
 public class MyGui {
     private class SaveAction implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           ....
        }
    }

     private class LoadAction implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           ....
        }
    }

 public void createMenuBar() {
   ...
   saveItem.addActionListener(new SaveAction());
   loadItem.addActionListener(new LoadAction());
 } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used to call this method in the main method but now I don't and I forgot to get rid of static. What, specifically, is bad about using static in code?

Comment: I don't think we have the scope here to explain all the problems with `static`. However, in the `main` function write sth such as `new MyGui().show()`, and create and display your gui in the `show()` method. If you run into problems a new SO question might be in place.

Comment: @admiralmattbar There are lots of reasons why static is considered bad practice - do some research into global variables. One problem is they don’t allow write control, so some other part of your program can change the reference and suddenly you have unpredictable behaviour. They also couple your core and reduce reusability and limit expansion- as some points